# Interacting electrons in 1D

Tags: bosonization

In Senechal’s review on Bosonization https://arxiv.org/pdf/cond-mat/9908262.pdf he starts with a microscopic Hamiltonian

$$H_{\mathrm{F}}=\sum_{k} \varepsilon(k) c^{\dagger}(k) c(k)$$

before stating that the low-energy Theory is defined in terms of creation/annihilation operators in the vicinity of the Fermi points

$$\begin{aligned} \alpha(k) &=c\left(k_{F}+k\right) \\ \alpha(-k) &=c\left(-k_{F}-k\right) \\ \beta(k) &=c^{\dagger}\left(k_{F}-k\right) \\ \beta(-k) &=c^{\dagger}\left(-k_{F}+k\right) \end{aligned}$$
And he concludes that the non interacting Hamiltonian takes the form

$$H_{\mathrm{F}}=\int \frac{\mathrm{d} k}{2 \pi} v|k|\left\{\alpha^{\dagger}(k) \alpha(k)+\beta^{\dagger}(k) \beta(k)\right\}$$

I’m not sure exactly how he used these creation/annihilation operators to get the Hamiltonian in this form. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea is that we linearize the spectrum about the two Fermi points $k_F$ and $-k_F$. As they are far apart, we can treat each one of them separately and label the excitations about $k_F$ and $-k_F$ as different species of electrons, $\alpha_k$ and $\beta_k$. The spectrum is linear and therefore the Hamiltonian is of the given form.

Technically what was done is to replace the quadratic dispersion plus half filling with two independent linearized spectrums about each Fermi point, stretching from $-\infty$ to $\infty$. This is a central approximation in the process of bosonization.

In [Miranda's review of bosonization](http://www.sbfisica.org.br/bjp/files/v33_3.pdf), this is depicted in figures 2 and 3 on page 6.